# Multiply two (2) columns of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please I need to multiply total no of jobtype and the value of `MEAL_Ticket` for a particular date

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DATENAME(dw, Time) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Time, 107) AS Date_to_Display,Vale,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog AS c 
     WHERE c.Time= clog.Time AND jobtype = 'fulltime') AS Fulltime,
    (SELECT COUNT(Jobtype) * SUM(Value) FROM CanLog 
     WHERE Time BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-02-14' AND jobtype = 'fulltime' ) AS FulltimeTicket_Value,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog AS c 
     WHERE c.Time = clog.Time AND jobtype = 'contract') AS Contract,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog AS c 
     WHERE c.Time = clog.Time AND jobtype = 'casual') AS Casual
FROM 
    CanLog AS clog
WHERE 
    Time BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-02-14' 
GROUP BY 
    Time, Jobtype 
ORDER BY 
    2 ASC
```

I got this error

> Column 'CanLog.Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

What I want is this output:

```
           Fulltime   FulltimeTicket_Value     Contract       Casual
2018/06/04         1       500(1*500)                  6            2
2018/06/05         3      1500(3*500)                  0            0
2018/06/06         0       0  (0*500)                  3            1
2018/06/07         2      1000(2*500)                  1            0
2018/06/08         1       500(1*500)                  1            3
2018/06/09         0         0(0*500)                  1            4
```

Please help

EDIT:

Sample table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CanLog]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Firstname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Jobtype] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Employ_No] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Receipt_No] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
    [Value] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) please :)

Comment: How does "value of MEAL_Ticket" fit into the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial query has a lot of warning signs:

- GROUP BY does not match SELECT
- DISTINCT + GROUP BY
- unnecessary subqueries could be replaced with conditional aggregation
- positional ORDER BY
- I would recommend to avoid column names such as Value/Time
- `Datename(dw, Time) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Time, 107)` I would replace it with `CAST(Time AS DATE)`
- `Time BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-02-14'`  this kind of comparison may be dangerous (as mentioned by @Gordon)

I believe you want something like:

```
SELECT 
    Date_to_Display = CAST(Time AS DATE),
    Fulltime = SUM(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'fulltime' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END),
    FulltimeTicket_Value = SUM(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'fulltime' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) *
                               MAX(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'fulltime' THEN Value ELSE 0 END),
    Contract = SUM(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'contract' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Casual = SUM(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'casual' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    CanLog AS clog
WHERE 
    Time >= '2018-02-12' and time < '2018-02-15' 
GROUP BY 
    CAST(Time AS DATE)
ORDER BY 
    CAST(Time AS DATE);
```

Comment: Heelo Lukasz the date are  not displaying in order  manner.it should be monday,tuesday ,wednesday ,but i got                                                        Monday, Feb 12, 2018
Thursday, Feb 15, 2018
Tuesday, Feb 13, 2018
Wednesday, Feb 14, 2018                                                                                                                                            lastly  i would want to display 0 as result instead of null

Comment: @lingers Date as text != date as date. I propose to handle formatting on application level.

Comment: Lukasz please help me edit the code to reflect my needs.Thanks

Comment: @lingers I've already changed my query. Just refresh webpage.

Comment: i have tried it i got this error.Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: @lingers So use `DATETIME` instead. I guess that your SQL Server is older than 2008

Comment: @LukaszSzozda . . . You should add `between` on date/time types to your list of warnings.

Comment: @lingers You didn't prepare sample data so I cannot test it. Please do not expect to get solution that you will only copy&paste and run. This is not how things works in SO. I suggest to copy my query, make adjustments and confirm if it works or not.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda my sql server is 2014 and i have added the sample Table in mssql.I used DateTime

Comment: @lingers [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9ab34faafd20e1bf55b2e3ac4a1d3b3)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda  I cast to datetime it worked but i dont need that format

Comment: @LukaszSzozda what do i do

Comment: @LukaszSzozda  i installed mssql 2014 it worked perfectly well  but the  days of the week does not appear.Please help

Answer (score 1):

In addition to many of the points that Lukasz makes, you should avoid using `between` on date/time columns.  A very good explanation is in Aaron Bertrand's blog [What do Between and the Devil Have In Common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

You can also simplify the logic using indicator variables:

```
select cast(time as date) as Date_to_Display,
       sum(is_fulltime) as Fulltime,
       sum(value * is_fulltime) as FulltimeTicket_Value,
       sum(is_contract) as Contract,
       sum(is_casual) as Casual
from CanLog cl cross apply
     (values (case when cl.jobtype = 'fulltime' then 1 else 0 end),
             (case when cl.jobtype = 'contract' then 1 else 0 end),
             (case when cl.jobtype = 'casual' then 1 else 0 end)
     ) v(is_contract, iscasual)
where Time >= '2018-02-12' and time < '2018-02-15' 
group by cast(time as date) 
order by cast(time as date);
```